# Simple PIPE program does reads strange characters

Tags: c, pipe

I have created a straightforward program with processes that does one very basic thing: the child writes, the father reads.
Strangely, the father only read strange characters and I do not know why (I've been trying for past hour to deduct why, but no success.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// cp = Child -> Parent,  pc = Parent -> child
int cp[2], pc[2];
int main (){
    char str[13]="Hello World";
    char received[13];
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1){
        printf("An error occured!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int res = pipe(cp);
    if (res == -1){
        printf("Error when creating pipe!..\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //pipe(pc);
    if (pid==0){
        // Child process
        close(cp[0]);
        write(cp[1], str, 10);
        close(cp[1]);
        exit(0);
    }else{
        // Parent process
        close(cp[1]);
        read(cp[0], received, 10);
        close(cp[0]);
        printf("We received from child: %s\n", received);
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Examples of outputs:
1) We received from child: @
2) We received from child: �XCV�

Comment: why are you doing like this. `char str[13]="Hello World\0";` you don't need to add null termination with quotes, it's already added if you use double quotes.

Comment: sorry, that was just something desperate

Comment: @SnuKies You don't even need to put the size `char str[] = "Hello World";`

Comment: `read()` returns a value. Use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you create your pipe **after** that you fork your process.

```
int cp[2];
int res = pipe(cp); // create the pipe before
if (res == -1) {
    perror("pipe()");
    return 1;
}
pid_t pid = fork(); // so child and parent share the same pipe
if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork()");
    return 1;
}
```

[A tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) about pipe grant by codekaizer.

---

`read()` is used to read bytes from a file descriptor. It will not add a nul byte at the end of the buffer.

You must put it yourself:

```
char received[42];
ssize_t n = read(cp[0], received, sizeof received - 1);
if (n == -1) {
    perror("read()");
    return 1;
}
received[n] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", received);
```